# How would one find out about off the beaten path destinations in the country?

Tags: discussion

There is a question on the main site about the non-"tourist trap" locations but it got me thinking about how would one format a question for this forum about the odd locations to visit in the country?

For example when visiting Lithuania one could visit the [Devil's Museum](http://www.forteantimes.com/features/fortean_traveller/662/devil_museum_kaunas_lithuania.html) or in the Old Kaunas post office there was a postmarking stamp from the late 19th or early 20th century (granted this is 20+ years old info) that was still in use and you can have your post card stamped with it.

But unless one knows these are there I can't see a good format for a question to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of sounding like "Google it", would Lonely Planet be likely to mention it?

Comment: If it's in Lonely Planet it's now most definitely *on* the beaten path.

Comment: @hippietrail: It depends on whether you're solely looking for places that not many other people go to, or whether you're wanting to go to places that the "average" tourist wouldn't want to go to.